# Effect on page operation if page is too big in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

In one of my requirements, I get the log file (can be around 10MB) from my WebServer, and display a `table with its content as log entries` (using javascript). The problem I face is that it `creates too many table rows`, due to which page becomes `less responsive`.

I want to know if too many objects in HTML makes a page slow ?

Also, what should be workaround for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you display the entries using javascript; is there an implied ajax call?

Comment: there is something called *pagination* u should try it

Comment: @BradChristie - yes, once the page is loaded, an ajax call is made to get the log data asynchronously.

Comment: @CodeHunter - thanx, i vl try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your javascript look like? Depending on how you're building the DOM, it could be the bottleneck. For example:

```
var html = [];
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    html.push('<tr><td>' + rows[i] + '</td></tr>'); 
}
$('#tbody').append(html.join(''));
```

is going to be a lot faster than

```
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    $('#tbody').append('<tr><td>' + rows[i] + '</td></tr>');        
}
```

This is assuming you're using jquery. Also, as others have mentioned, use pagination to keep limit the number of elements on the screen.

If your HTML is complex, you may want to look into a [template engine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/05/client-side-templating/), and some [help choosing](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) the one that is right for you. I use [dust](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/) because linkedin [did all the hard evaluation work](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Comment: thanx... now that I see, 1st approach is quite fast, it append to DOM only once, thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, given this is an AJAX call I see a few options (in order of best performance):

1. Add paging to the service call and allow the AJAX query to only pull down specific batches of entries. Then implement next/previous page buttons that would make successive calls to retrieve more/less information. e.g. `/ajax/log` would be your initial call, then clicking next button would call `/ajax/log?page=2`; Previous button re-calls `/ajax/log?page=1`.
2. Pull all the data down in a single call, but only selectively output it to the DOM. KnockoutJS makes ouputting information in a paging format very simple (and there are examples here on Stackoverfow).
3. Dump it as-s and add a script like jQuery DataTables. This will hide rows and implement paging based on what's been pushed in to the table itself. It requires very little additional programming other than load up the table via ajax, then call `$('mytable').datatable()`.

Comment: thanx, 2nd and 3rd options seems feasible to me, because one of my requirement says that user should also be able to save the file at client side